# Moving a file in c# without renaming it

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a collection of XML files I am looping through and moving the files that have errors to another file location. However when I'm using the system.io.file.move function it requires me to specify a file name instead of moving the file path. Is there a way I can move the file from one location to another while keeping the same name? I am currently creating a name based on the position of the file in the array which isn't really feasible.

```
string ErrorPath = string.Format(@"{1}ErroredXml{0}.xml", errorLength, errorPaths);

//If type equals "add" then call add method else call update
if (Equals(type, typecomp))
{
    //pass object to data access layer to add record
    value.addNewGamePlay();

    if (value.getGamePlayID() == 0)
    {
        //move to error file
        System.IO.File.Move(value.getFile(), ErrorPath);
        errorLength++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to extract the original file name and construct the destination path with it using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

```
var original = value.getFile();
var destinationPath = Path.Combine(errorPaths, Path.GetFileName(original));
```

Answer (score -1):

Move method does not require to change name of file.
the second argument is not a new name to file but a new path to file
for example

first argument (sourceFileName)
@"c:\temp\MyTest.txt"

second argument (destFileName)
@"c:\temp2\MyTest.txt"

so file name is same "MyTest.txt" just position is changed.